# Kivy doesn't play sound file the first time play() is called

Tags: python, audio, kivy

I run a simple Kivy app on Windows. A button executes following method from the Kivy docs ([link](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.audio.html)) when pressed:

```
def play_audio(self):
    sound = SoundLoader.load('output.wav')
    if sound:
        print("Sound found at %s" % sound.source)
        print("Sound is %.3f seconds" % sound.length)
        sound.play()
```

The first time the button is pressed, it either plays about half a second of sound and then immediately stops or it's not playing anything at all. When I press the button again it plays the entire file as expected.

Why isn't it playing the file on the first button press and how do I get it to work properly?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running the kivy eventloop? You are probably getting interrupted

Comment: I assume eventloop means MyApp().run() (sorry I'm new to this). If so than yes, it's running. I think if the problem was related to the main loop than it wouldn't make any sense for it to work the 2nd time I clicked the button (unless I'm missing something, which is entirely possible).

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166589/preloading-sound-in-kivy) thread will be useful. Try loading the sound once before the button is even pressed like so:

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import time

sound = SoundLoader.load('output.wav')
sound.seek(0)

class MyLabel(Button):
    def on_release(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        self.play_sound()
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    def play_sound(self):
        if sound:
            print("Sound found at %s" % sound.source)
            print("Sound is %.3f seconds" % sound.length)
            sound.play()

runTouchApp(MyLabel(text="Press me for a sound"))
```

The `play_sound()` function took about ten times less time to complete on my machine if you do `sound.seek(0)`.

Comment: Sorry for the (very) late reply, I was away. I think I actually tried that (I found that thread during my research) and it didn't fix the issue. I'll try it again when I have the time. Also I just realized that I didn't install kivy.deps.gstreamer (https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#kivy-dependencies) I'll check later if gstreamer fixes it.

Comment: Yeah, gstreamer might help. Let me know how it goes if you have the time, I'm very interested...